# error: invalid use of non-static member

Tags: c++

The compiler throws: "invalid use of non-static member 'it', why is this ?
The inheritance is correct but I dont understand why it doesnt let me use it and the allInfo vector.

```
class JSON{

    private:
    vector<myType> allInfo;

    public:

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,const JSON &js)
    {
        vector<myType>::iterator it;
        it = this->allInfo.begin();

        for(it; it != allInfo.end();it++){
            cout << "this is the info "<<(it->getNAME()) << endl;
        }
        return os;
    };

};
```

Comment: You want `js.allInfo` (and `const_iterator`). `operator<<` here is not a member of `JSON`; in order to access members of `JSON`, you need to specify the object you want to get them from. Luckily, one is handily passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

operator<< is a `friend` function, it's not actually a member of the class `JSON`. Therefore, if you just say `allInfo`, the compiler doesn't know what `allInfo` you're talking about.

However, the correct `JSON` instance is passed as a parameter. You should write lines like this:

```
it = js.allInfo.begin();
/* ... */
for(it; it != js.allInfo.end();it++){
```

Now, you're telling the compiler you want to use the `allInfo` that belongs to instance `js`.